# Firabase query with multiple where and order

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a query for `firebase/firestore` but I am getting an error because I have 2 `where` and both of them are inequalities and I cant put more than 1 inequality for some reason. This is my code:

```js
const packagesRef = db
      .collection('packages');

const query = packagesRef
        .where('invoice', '!=', null)
        .where('creationTime', '>=', 0)
        .orderBy('creationTime', 'desc')
        .orderBy('invoice', 'desc');
```

The error that I am getting:

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties: [invoice, creationTime]

I tried changing the order:

```js
const packagesRef = db
      .collection('packages');

const query = packagesRef
        .where('creationTime', '>=', 0)
        .where('invoice', '!=', null)
        .orderBy('invoice', 'desc')
        .orderBy('creationTime', 'desc')
```

Also the `opStr` argument in `invoice`:

```js
const packagesRef = db
      .collection('packages');

const query = packagesRef
        .where('invoice', '>=', 0)
        .where('creationTime', '>=', 0)
        .orderBy('creationTime', 'desc')
        .orderBy('invoice', 'desc');
```

But still the same result. Is there a way to do that or is imposible?

Comment: As the error message says: Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties. So you can't do `>=` on one field and then `!=` on another field. The order doesn't matter for that, it's the conditions that trigger the error.